# I want to load the dump file inside of my docker container

Tags: docker, neo4j, dockerfile, database-migration

I created a "database.dump" file of my local neo4j database, and then created a docker image that also contains that database.dump file. I now want to load that .dump file inside of my docker container. I have tried : docker exec --interactive --tty <containerID/name> neo4j-admin load --from=(path inside docker) --database=neo4j --force.

I keep getting neo4j-admin : not found.
How could I resolve this?
The internal structure of my docker image is shown in attached image [Docker Image File System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jbnlf.png)

**The primary purpose is to migrate my database from local to a docker container!**

Comment: can you show the Dockerfile?

Comment: what you want to do with docker files is to expose both database files as well as probably your dump file in a mounted directory... Also note that the path might be relative to the Neo4j folder and not root folder

Answer (score 0):

First, find the ID of the Docker container running `docker ps` in the terminal.

Once you have the container id, you can simply copy the dump file from the file system to the Docker container:

```
docker cp ./database.dump 14893b1a654c:/var/lib/neo4j/import/database.dump
```

Comment: Hey thankyou! But when I try to load the file it shows me neo4j is running and for loading the dump file neo4j needs to be stopped in the container, whereas at the same time container should be running!